# Yii - How to use scenarios to validate only visible form fields?

Tags: forms, yii, yii2

I have a multi-step form that will be submitted on the final step.
The user should be able to go back and forward as he/she pleases.
So, I believe I have to use the same form, but visually split it, using css and js.

Upon each "next" button click, I wish to validate the form using *Yii Scenarios* rules defined.

I'm trying to think on an approach to trigger the validation, only on visible fields (for that single step).

My thought:

1. Create the model and activeform
2. Create the *scenarios* that should be triggered based on a *flag*
3. On each "next" click, send an ajax call, that will be consumed by
   the *controller*, and than sent to the *model*, and use it as a flag to
   trigger a *scenario*.

Does this makes sense? Or is there a better approach for doing this?

Comment: This is probably how I'd do it too. I'd use the step number to determine the scenario.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this approach.

Comment: I think we would have a problem with this implementation because: the form is only rendered at once. How will it write the "required" element on the client side?

Comment: Hmm. An alternative would be to render the form each time via ajax. That way you can set the scenario in the controller to determine what fields would be shown and validated for.

Comment: @topher: It seems to. But it is a little to much go and come for such a validation. If we do that, it would be better to assume something more substancial, for example, using the ajax call to also save on a temporary table. Is something to consider in the future. For now,we are grabbing the form all together on one request, and we split the all thing via javascript. Since Yii has a "has-error" class, we can retrieve the validation for each visible step. Seems a nice solution for now. What say you?

Comment: Is there any chance that cleverly setting the "skipOnEmpty" attribute will solve your problem? That way you'll only validate fields actually submitted for validation.

Comment: You could validate each input type on focusout (rather than keyUp) that's not hidden and make a check when clicking next step if each inputs are validated?

Answer (score 0):

Your are doing good , I think for each step make a action like action , and make scenarios according to the step . for example

in first step you want to validation for name , age etc , make a scenario for it and action for and same thing for next step. so you can validate each steps according to your choice.